# Spring Integration application does not define channels when executed as packaged jar

Tags: maven, spring-integration

I started to use Spring Integration in a project at work. Everything was looking fine and running smoothly on my local dev environment (when executed from Eclipse).

However, when I tried to deploy to our dev/staging environment I got some issues related with the definition of the Spring Integration channels.

After a couple of hours completely clueless (blaming external dependencies, our development/staging environment setup etc etc), I came to realize that I would get exactly the same issue whenever I tried to execute my application as a **packaged jar** (on my local machine)

I did a small "sample" application without any other dependencies in order to reproduce this issue. Once again everything works fine from eclipse but whenever executed as a packaged jar the following exception was thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'gatewayChannel' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:46)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.getRequestChannel(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:344)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:385)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:481)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:433)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:424)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.App$RealApp.doThings(App.java:52)
    at com.test.App.main(App.java:62)
```

Bellow you can find the code of my sample application and the pom that I used to build my packaged jar.

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
public class App {

  @MessagingGateway
  public interface GatewayApp {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "gatewayChannel")
    void send(String string);
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow inboud() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("gatewayChannel")
        .handle(System.out::println)
        .get();
  }

  @Component
  public class RealApp {
    @Autowired
    private GatewayApp gateway;

    public void doThings() {
      gateway.send("yeee");
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("resource")
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.register(App.class);
    context.refresh();
    context.getBean(RealApp.class).doThings();
  }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sprint-integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>integration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>integration</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.3.14.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <createSourcesJar>false</createSourcesJar>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>yo-service</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Note: I think this issue might have exaclty the same cause as the one reported in [Spring integration bootstrap - intellij in debug works, packaged jar does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685182/spring-integration-bootstrap-intellij-in-debug-works-packaged-jar-does-not)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is the shade plugin is having some effect on the order in which `BeanPostProcessors` are run.

Does the app work if you explicitly define the channel...

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel gatewayChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

...?

If so, that would be a smoking gun. In that case, the next step would be to get a DEBUG log for `org.springframework` in both environments and compare the bean definition/creation/post processing logs.

If you can post a complete (simple) example that exhibits the problem, we can take a look.

**EDIT**

The problem is the shade plugin does not merge the `META-INF/spring.factories` files, so we lose the entry from the JAVA DSL and hence don't process any `IntegrationFlow`s...

From the Uber jar we just have the core file...

```
org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationConfigurationInitializer=\
org.springframework.integration.config.GlobalChannelInterceptorInitializer,\
org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationConverterInitializer,\
org.springframework.integration.config.IdempotentReceiverAutoProxyCreatorInitializer
```

and so are missing the additional initializer from the DSL jar...

```
org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationConfigurationInitializer=\
org.springframework.integration.dsl.config.DslIntegrationConfigurationInitializer
```

Hence it works with 5.0.1 because the DSL is now part of core.

Spring Boot [solves this problem](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-executable-jar) by nesting the jars instead of extracting all the classes.

**EDIT2**

Here's another work-around, if you can't move to Spring Integration 5. Add this bean to your application...

```
@Bean
public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor dslInitializer() {
    return new BeanFactoryPostProcessor() {

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf) throws BeansException {
            new DslIntegrationConfigurationInitializer().initialize(bf);
        }

    };
}
```

(Notice `static`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gary. I did a sample "minimal" application that reproduces the error. The code is right above the pom.xml that I just posted. I remember to try to define the channel explicitly on my original project. When I did that I would get some different error, something like "the channel had no subscribers".

Comment: I googled a bit more, can it be that this is the same issue as the one reported here: https://jira.spring.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/INT-4074

Comment: I just created a project from the above and reproduced. It might be related to that JIRA; I too get the dispatcher as has no subs when declaring the channel. Definitely smells like a BPP problem. Investigating...

Comment: It works with Spring Integration 5.0.1.RELEASE - probably because the DSL is now part of the `-core` artifact (you don't need the separate `-java-dsl` artifact). `GenericMessage [payload=yeee, headers={id=d52ed601-8f45-4166-262d-8b27f8f591a0, timestamp=1518363996970}]`

Comment: Correction to the correction; I was right; the problem is because the shade plugin doesn't know how to merge `META-INF/spring.factories` files. See my edit.

Comment: FYI, I just exploded the uber jar, fixed the `spring.factories` file, re-jar'd it and it works.

Comment: I added another workaround, for if you can't move to SI 5.

Comment: I cannot move to SI 5 so I've used the workaround you proposed. Everything is working fine now. Thanks for the help

Comment: [Added documentation about how to use Spring Boot's shaded jar extension](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2360).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Gary Russell's answer: The problem is indeed that the `META-INF/spring.factories` files are not automatically merged by the shade plugin.

You can use the [AppendingTransformer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer) of the shade plugin to merge these files.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.my.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                </transformers>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```